# if statement to find conflict in transaction table

Tags: java, database

[image: this is the transaction table i want to find the conflict in it.]

I'm working on java project that finds the conflict in table transaction like(read after write) for the same object. and draw a conflict graph for the table.

I've tried to write an if statement that gives the output for the conflict graph but i couldn't.I'm stuck on the statement that finds the conflict actions and returns the result.
any advice?

the code for the draw conflict button :

```
        int rowsNum=tTable.getRowCount();
        int columnsNum=tTable.getColumnCount();
        String[][] tableArray = new String[rowsNum][columnsNum];
        System.out.println("rows num is: " +rowsNum+" and columns num  is: "+columnsNum);
        String res=null;

        for(int cc=0;cc<columnsNum;cc++)    // this loop to read data from table and put into array.
        {
        for(int rr=0;rr<rowsNum;rr++){
        res=(String) tTable.getModel().getValueAt(rr, cc);
        tableArray[rr][cc]=res;
        }
        }
        int counter1=0;
        for (int ra=0;ra<rowsNum;ra++){   // this loop to print table width=3dd il rows
        for (int ca=0;ca<columnsNum;ca++){      

        System.out.print(" item: "+tableArray[ra][ca]);
        if(tableArray[ra][ca].equals("Write=a")){
           for (int cca=ca+1;cca<columnsNum;cca++)
           {
           for (int rra=0;rra<rowsNum;rra++)
          {
          if (tableArray[rra][cca].equals("Write=a") || tableArray[ra][ca].equals("Read=a"))
          {
          System.out.println("there is a conflict between index:"+ra+":"+ca+": and :"+rra+":"+cca );
          }
          }
           }
                          for (int cca=ca-1;cca>=0;cca++)
           {
           for (int rra=0;rra<rowsNum;rra++)
          {
          if (tableArray[rra][cca].equals("Write=a") || tableArray[ra][ca].equals("Read=a"))
          {
          System.out.println("there is a conflict between index:"+ra+":"+ca+": and :"+rra+":"+cca );
          }
          }
           }
        counter1++;
        }    
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        }
                    System.out.println("my counter: "+counter1);
```

I want to get the conflict location but the output of the if statement do not appear at all.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I've edited the question and added the code please see the question again, thank you

Comment: Do not compare strings with ==. Only with `equals()`.

Comment: thank you, it solved a part of the problem.

Comment: could you please see the edited code again? what is the wrong with the if statement that chick the conflict?